# Dynamically apply XSL template?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML code and a XSLT. Inside the XSLT I have several templates.
In one case I need to re-use a already translated part of the XML a second, third, .... time.

I have some sample code here:

```
    <!-- XML imput -->

<!-- this is a definition -->
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
<pardef id='defId1' keepwithnext='true' keeptogether='true'>
    <code event='hidewhen'>
        <formula>
        Foo=""
        </formula>
    </code>
</pardef>

<!-- the definition is used here by referncing the id -->
<par def='defId1'>
    <field type='text' kind='editable' name='bar'/>
</par>
<!-- and a second one -->
<par def='defId1'>
    <field type='text' kind='editable' name='bar'/>
</par>
</root>
```

My XSL:

```
<!-- XSL -->

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
<!-- template which should be applied -->
<xsl:template match="dxl:field|dxl:sharedfieldref" name="field">
    <!-- do some stuff here -->
</xsl:template>


<!-- ??? cannot be a static name but should compute from the template name (which is pardef) and the given id
<xsl:when test="parent::dxl:par">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="???"/>
</xsl:when>
</root>
```

The resulting code should be something like this:

```
<par formula="...">
<field.../>
</par>

<par formula="...">
<field.../>
</par>
```

I already have a template for the pardef which should be applied again.
I hope you can follow me ;-)
BTW: I am using Webstorm's XSL Transformation - but I can't name which processor is used.

Any help for the Xpath selector is appreciated!

Comment: Please split your code samples in to "input", "xsl" and "expected output" parts and make them correct (document element, namespace definitions, syntax) and complete (no hand-waving, make a self-contained MCVE). Also, include details about the XSLT processor you are using.

Comment: Not sure I get what is the crux of the issue. You want to apply a template on some "pardef" and do the selection based on the current "par" node's "def" attribute?

Comment: I want to find the content, apply the corresponding template and all this depending on the def attribute value